# reinstall package

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have created a new component, inserted into a new package, installed and it worked. (it appeared in the pallette). After a time I wanted to modify that component and accidentally deleted the *.bpl from the Delphi/projects/bpl folder, also Delphi asked me if I want to reload the missing *.bpl ant the next start and said no. After all that, I wanted to install again the modified component and it does not appear in the pallete. What can I do? I don't want to reinstall Delphi....

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem solved (by mistake)

I just opened the palette, selected [All], and clicked on Default Pages... and my custom package appeared (with my component).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking, but why not install the component into a new package again?   It seems to me you accidently deleted the package, but not the component.   So try the following:

```
> Open the component source code  
> Under the component menu, click Install Component 
> Click on the Into New package tab 
> Name the package and click OK
```

This should install the component for you...